# Android отправка URL ссылки через JavaMAILapi

Tags: java, android, email

Столкнулся с проблемой, пытаюсь передать письмо ссылкой и координатами [такого вида](https://www.google.com.ua/maps/place/49.9482427,36.2910241).

После как пришло письмо ссылка обрублена, предполагаю, что нужно экранировать символ `','`.
[image: письмо]

```
private void sendMail() 
{
    String latitudeGeo = mLatitudeTextView.getText().toString();
    String longTitudeGeo = mLongitudeTextView.getText().toString();
    String mail = channelSneMassage;

    // String mail = test_email;
    String message = myLocation + System.lineSeparator() + " " + System.lineSeparator() + googleMapsLocation + latitudeGeo + "," + longTitudeGeo + System.lineSeparator() + System.lineSeparator() + position;
    String subject = "Тема";

    //Send Mail
    JavaMailAPI javaMailAPI = new JavaMailAPI(getActivity(),mail,subject,message);
    javaMailAPI.execute();           
}
```